# Error when running the WordCount example pipeline on Dataflow with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-dataflow

When trying to run the WordCount example pipeline using Dataflow under Eclipse IDE, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:150)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:178)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
    ... 4 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing object or bucket in path: 'gs://mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008-my-bucket/', did you mean: 'gs://some-bucket/mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008-my-bucket'?
    at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:383)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPath(GcsPathValidator.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:246)
    ... 9 more
```

Some people suggest that the error is due to the Java version, as it seems that Beam doesn't work fine with Java 9. Anyway, I'm still using Java 8. On the other hand, some other people say that the error is caused because you have to provide  a subfolder under your bucket as the storage location. I've tried, but it still does not work.

If anyone faced this same issue before or can provide any advice on the error, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The "subfolder under your bucket"  bit that you mentioned is the one mentioned in the error trace? This:
`did you mean: 'gs://some-bucket/mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008-my-bucket'`

Comment: Thank you @Mangu. No, that seems to be the compiler's suggestion. If I'm not wrong, no buckets under other buckets are allowed, so that's why it results weird to me.

Comment: It seems that will work by uncheck the flag "Use Default Dataflow options". See this [Similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864619/dataflow-pipeline-missing-object-or-bucket-in-path).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dataflow pipeline Missing object or bucket in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864619/dataflow-pipeline-missing-object-or-bucket-in-path)

Comment: Hi Mangu' suggestion is correct. You need to assign a folder instead of bucket name only for the cloud storage staging location. Refer to my post here about all the details:[link](http://kontext.tech/docs/DataAndBusinessIntelligence/p/load-csv-file-from-google-cloud-storage-to-bigquery-using-dataflow#Exception_in_thread_%22main%22_java.lang.RuntimeException:_Failed_to_construct_instance_from_factory_method_DataflowRunner#fromOptions)

Answer (score 0):

You should create bucket `gs://mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008-my-bucket/` in Google Cloud Storage before use the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Create mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008-my-bucket in the GCP Project.

For Bucket Creation :
Go to GCP UI, select Storage Bucket. Click Create Bucket Button. Enter Bucket name mysite-ga-datastreaming-196008-my-bucket. Click ok.
Then run the command.