# Dataflow pipeline Missing object or bucket in path

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In Eclipse i am running WordCount Dataflow pipeline. Running locally works. But switching to Cloud i get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing object or bucket in path: 'gs://tough-shard-129113/', did you mean: 'gs://some-bucket/tough-shard-129113'?
```

Of course the bucket exists. Any suggestion? I use Java8.
thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is `tough-shard-129113` the real name of your bucket? Because I could create a bucket named `tough-shard-129113` and the names are global unique.

Comment: typo. It is tough-shard-189113 but still does not solve..

Comment: do you have full stack for this? And your parameters?

Comment: could you please try the following: 1. Check if the project is set correctly 2. try to use gs://tough-shard-129113/tmp instead of the bucket?

Comment: @ZhouYunqing thanks.I tried also gs://tough-shard-189113/tmp but same error:                                                      
         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing object or bucket in path: 'gs://tough-shard-189113/', did you mean: 'gs://some-bucket/tough-shard-189113'?
 at 
..

Comment: Got it, could you please try to execute "gsutil ls gs://tough-shard-189113/" on the same machine?

Comment: @toto' Could you please do what Zhou Yunqing asked with your Dataflow's project's Compute Engine service account?

Comment: When i run "gsutil ls gs://tough-shard-189113/" i got normal list of buckets underneath. But from Eclipse is still same error. @enlelin do you mean something different?

Comment: I just want ensure that your Dataflow can access to your bucket. Btw, is your bucket in the same project as your running Dataflow pipeline?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause of issue. In the picture you can see that the cloud storage staging location is empty. I tried to switch to another bucket but the error i get always points to  gs://tough-shard-189113/! And the location in the configuration is empty..

Comment: @enlelin yes, because i have only one project.

Comment: Ok. I managed to make it work. I unchecked the flag "Use Default Dataflow options". Thanks all for support.

Comment: Great! I would like to ask you to post your comment as an answer. Since it is easier for the community to see it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I managed to make it work. I unchecked the flag "Use Default Dataflow options". Thanks all for support. –

Answer (score 0):

After uncheck flag "Use Default Dataflow options" under Pipeline Arguments tab, we have to keep blank value for "Cloud Storage staging location".